# nested horizontal listview from vertical listview flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to put a horizontal listview inside a vertical listview but I get the following error :

_doThrowNew(
int assertionStart, int assertionEnd, Object? message);

```js
ListView.builder(
              itemCount: data!.length >= 8 ? 8 : data.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return Container(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(top: getProportionateScreenHeight(40)),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Text(data[index].username),
                      SizedBox(
                          height: 375,
                          child: ListView.builder(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              itemCount: data[index].posts.length,
                              itemBuilder: (_, indexx) => SizedBox(
                                  width: SizeConfig.screenWidth * 0.8,
                                  child: HomePost(
                                    item: data[index].posts[indexx],
                                    iconOne:
                                        'assets/icons/measure-meter-tape-tool-svgrepo-com.svg',
                                  )))),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest
For the first time, I see such an error only when I reach the last card in the horizontal listview. This error appears, marked in yellow, inside a page titled (errors_patch.dart)

Comment: Did you try to give the container that you return a height??
I faced some thing similar, and solve it by giving the container a height

Comment: Can you create a simple widget that will reproduce the same error.  Find more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I received this message in DEBUG CONSOLE 'package:flutter/src/widgets/overscroll_indicator.dart': Failed assertion: line 243 pos 14: 'notification.metrics.axis == widget.axis': is not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching, I found that the problem is almost an overscroll of a horizontal ListView inside another ListView

After following the console, I found this message explaining the problem

'package:flutter/src/widgets/overscroll_indicator.dart': Failed assertion: line 243 pos 14: 'notification.metrics.axis == widget.axis': is not true.

I searched for this problem and then found the solution
set property **physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),**

I don't really know exactly what it's doing, but I'm sure I'll get to know it

full code :

```js
ListView.builder(
              itemCount: data!.length >= 8 ? 8 : data.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return Container(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(top: getProportionateScreenHeight(40)),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Text(data[index].username),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 375,
                        child: ListView(
                            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                            reverse: true,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            children: data[index].posts.map((e) {
                              return SizedBox(
                                  width: SizeConfig.screenWidth * 0.8,
                                  child: ProfilePost(
                                    item: e,
                                    iconOne:
                                        'assets/icons/measure-meter-tape-tool-svgrepo-com.svg',
                                  ));
                            }).toList()),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
```